# Single app which manages multiple email accounts of a user

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which manages multiple email account of a single user.Question is how to sync email accounts(gmail,yahoo, AOl,etc) to my app? through web services or using single apis for each emails.

Is there any API available in android to sync email accounts?

reference app:-  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.freenet.mail&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You would manage each email account using its provider's API/Web Service.

I would advice you to check each Email Provider API reference and integrate them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are slower than provided API's, so the default and more clear solution will be the use of single API for each email.

Example : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/